# Compiling of the solution working fine but when trying to do dotnet publish using cli facing the following

Tags: c#

C:..\sdk\6.0.401\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4099,5): error MSB4062: The "Microsoft.Build.Tasks.RequiresFramework35SP1Assembly" task could not be loaded from the assembly msbuild.Core, Version= 15.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.

Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets:

```
<RequiresFramework35SP1Assembly
      ReferencedAssemblies="@(Reference)"
        ErrorReportUrl="$(_DeploymentFormattedErrorReportUrl)"
        TargetFrameworkVersion="$(TargetFrameworkVersion)"
        CreateDesktopShortcut="$(CreateDesktopShortcut)"
        SigningManifests="$(SignManifests)"
        Assemblies="@(_DeploymentManifestDependencies)"

<Output TaskParameter="RequiresMinimumFramework35SP1" PropertyName="_DeploymentRequiresMinimumFramework35SP1" />
</RequiresFramework35SP1Assembly>
```

Comment: Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.